# jQuery multiple autocomplete with different input IDs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use jQuery autocomplete and have multiple input fields with different IDs, and they are populated from a MySQL database.

```
  $("#CCU1").autocomplete({
  minLength : 1,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo site_url().'gsimc/autocomplete'; ?>",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { 
        term  : $("#CCU1").val(),
        column: 'course',
        tbl   : 'tbl_courses'
      },
      success: function(data){
        if(data.response == 'true') {
          response(data.message);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The input fields has IDs of CCU1...CCU5, name='course'. Any idea how to autocomplete the five input fields instead of hardcoding each one?

```
Course1: <input type='text' name='course[]' id='CCU1'/><br />
Course2: <input type='text' name='course[]' id='CCU2'/><br />
Course3: <input type='text' name='course[]' id='CCU3'/><br />
Course4: <input type='text' name='course[]' id='CCU4'/><br />
Course5: <input type='text' name='course[]' id='CCU5'/><br />
```

Comment: A pattern you can use: add a dummyclass to each element like `.autocompleteHandler` and refer to the class as the selector `$('.autocompleteHandler').autocomplete()`, and use the reference to `$(this)` inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your above code is working for one of them, you could do:

```
$("[id^=CCU]").each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      minLength : 1,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo site_url().'gsimc/autocomplete'; ?>",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { 
            term  : $(this).val(),
            column: 'course',
            tbl   : 'tbl_courses'
          },
          success: function(data){
            if(data.response == 'true') {
              response(data.message);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `$(this)` instead of hardcoding the ID:

```
term: $("#CCU1").val(),
```

Replace it with:

```
term: $(this).val(),
```

#### Full code:

```
$("[id^=CCU]").each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      minLength : 1,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo site_url().'gsimc/autocomplete'; ?>",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { 
            term  : $(this).val(),
            column: 'course',
            tbl   : 'tbl_courses'
          },
          success: function(data){
            if(data.response == 'true') {
              response(data.message);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get an error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: That `toLowerCase` function is not used in the above script. Can you show us the full code?

Comment: The error is in jquery.min.js, I have no problem showing the autocomplete for just one input field though.

Comment: I really can't figure this one out. I tried everything all of you have suggested and still getting the uncaught type error thingy. Maybe I need to sleep this out first. :(

Comment: `this` inside `$.ajax` isn't what you think it is. Declare a variable `var $this=$(this)` before calling `$.ajax` and use that variable instead

Comment: This worked for me to get the id of the element being used: $(this)[0].element.attr('id')

Comment: @MarcSchluper Amazing, thanks. Glad to hear. Noted this and will also update in the answer.